# Prevent error on int(input()) that is a string and prevent negative number input

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

this is a very simple question which I have forgotten but for the code I have listed, how would I go about ensuring that no error pops up when a string is input, and also how do I return the question again if there a negative number is input.

```
roomChoice = int(input("Which room would you like to book?: "))
```

Hoping to get a response that is clear and concise as I have to explain this in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` and `except`:

```py
while True:
    try: # the block of code below 'try' is being tested
        roomChoice = int(input("Which room would you like to book?: "))
        if isinstance(roomChoice, int) and roomChoice >= 0:  # if roomChoice is an positive int exit the loop
            break
    except ValueError as e: # following is what happens if there's a ValueError
        print(f'An {e} error occured! Input an integer!')
```

Documentation on `try` and `except`: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

OR

You can use `pyinputplus` module:

```py
import pyinputplus as pyip
roomChoice = pyip.inputInt(prompt="Which room would you like to book?: ", min=0)
```